# Flute melody from classical symphony

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I have tried [midomi](http://www.midomi.com/), [SoundHound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melodis.midomiMusicIdentifier.freemium&hl=en), and Kooplet to no avail. My search on Kooplet contains the part I remember and can be listened to on [this page](http://www.kooplet.com/cgi-bin/kooplet/search.pl?w=G%20EbD%20C%20D%20EbG%20EbD%20C%20D%20EbD%20EbG%20EbD%20C%20D%20EbG%20EbD%20C%20D%20EbD%20Eb&s=pe-&q=37403340324030403240334037403340324030403220332032203320&p=S:0;D:20160;P:0;H:1;R:1;L:0;&t=a).

I know that this part is performed by the flute. What is the name of the symphony?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it's ["Morning Mood"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_Mood) from Edvard Grieg's *Peer Gynt* Suite No. 1.

*Peer Gynt* started life as incidental music to the play of the same name by Henrik Ibsen; it included vocal as well as instrumental parts. Grieg later made two purely orchestral suites from it, "Morning Mood" (or, popularly, just "Morning") being the opening movement of the first suite.